# Machine-generated header files

Tags: c, header, header-files

Specifically how do you generate machine-generated header files which usually have the following comment at the top /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */? Could someone provide an example?

Comment: You need to buy a machine that writes them for you...

Comment: I have written such comments on top of headers that I do not want juniors to mess with.

Comment: @Shark: you are an evil genius!

Comment: @PaulR Being one of the last modders of the said game, thanks for the compliments, but I learned from the best :)

Comment: @ Kerrek @ Shark. Ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the file from which the header was automatically generated, and then re-generate a new header, otherwise if you modify the generated header your changes will be over-written next time a new header is generated.

Without further information it's not possible to know how your headers are generated - it could be a custom tool or script or it could be some sort of standard macro processor (e.g. m4).